# Как связать атрибут тега contenteditable <td> с БД mysql + jQuerry?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-form, contenteditable

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, делаю таблицу, там очень много ячеек td, содержимое которое виводится с БД phpmyadmin
например:

```
echo "<td contenteditable='true'>" . $row["id1"] . "</td>";
echo "<td contenteditable='true'>" . $row["id2"] . "</td>";
echo "<td contenteditable='true'>" . $row["id3"] . "</td>";
```

какой должен бить скрипт js и какой код php, чтоби если я хочу изменить ячеяку она записовала через UPDATE в базу данных?

Не знаю как  это сделать, пробовал только через input, button

Comment: 1) повесть на ячейки скрипт отслеживающие событие изменения контента. 2) собрать сопутствующие данные для редактируемой ячейки, которые надо отправить на бэк, а-ля имя поля,  или ID строки, или чего там у вас еще есть (это надо куда-то в верстку вывести тоже в виде атрибутов например) 3) отправить запрос на бэк 4) на бэке получить данные, сформировать запрос к БД и выполнить его

Comment: а вообще лучше посмотреть в сторону каких нить datatables, а не вот этого вот

Comment: 0



здесь смотреть? https://datatables.net/ это через js все ?

Comment: там, да. все не все но JS, конечно. От пхп только данные отдавать надо.